# Jenkins behaviour when using post-commit hook

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am using post-commit hook to automatically trigger a build for a job configured in Jenkins when user checks in code to Subversion.

When post-commit hook is used, will Jenkins parse out the svn repo url configured in all active jobs when a notifyCommit request is made?? Or will it parse out the svn repo url for a job only if 'poll scm' feature is turned on?

I need to know this because of late SVN is very slow or goes down after reaching its max clients limit(64). My Maxrequestsperchild is 64000. I have about 200 jobs in Jenkins and about 50 of them have 'poll scm' feature turned on.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it needs to have SCM polling enabled, but you can set up some rare schedule, like once a year.

***Edit:***
Here is a text from [**Subversion Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) documentation, in regards to using post-commit hooks

`Jobs on Jenkins need to be configured with the SCM polling option to benefit from this behavior. This is so that you can have some jobs that are never triggered by the post-commit hook (in the $REPOSITORY/hooks directory), such as release related tasks, by omitting the SCM polling option.
The configured polling can have any schedule (probably infrequent like monthly or yearly). The net effect is as if polling happens out of their usual cycles.`

What it is saying is that if you want a job to be triggered by post-commmit hook, you have to have that job configured with SCM polling (albeit it can be infrequent polling). The builds will happen as many times as the post-commit hook is called, independent of SCM polling interval.

This is done so that you can have a repository location configured with post-commit hooks, and an **automatic** build job that acts on the hook, while having another **manual** job for the same repository location but configured without SCM polling that would ignore the post-commit hook.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you mean only if 'poll scm' is enabled then Jenkins will parse out the SVN URL of the job? Or will Jenkins parse the SVN URL for every job even if 'poll scm' is not enabled?

Comment: When your post-commit hook sends a request to `http://jenkinsurl/subversion/repo_uuid/notifyCommit`, Jenkins will then figure out which jobs use that particular repo. Then it will check if SCM polling is enabled on those jobs. If yes, it will be triggered. If not, it will be ignored. So yes, SCM polling is required for post-commit to work

Comment: Let me ask my question in a different way. I have post commit hook setup. In Jenkins, I have two jobs- Job A with poll scm turned on and pointing to location /projA/ in SVN trunk. Job B does not have poll scm turned on and is pointing to location /projB/ in SVN trunk. When a user makes changes to projA, Jenkins gets notified of a commit in a certain URL ( say URL/projA). Now Jenkins goes to Job A and compares the SVN URL with URL/projA and its a match, so it triggers a build. Now my question is, will it compare SVN URL of proj B with URL/Proj A even when poll scm is turned off?

Comment: AFAIK, no. If SCM polling is turned off on `proj B`, Jenkins will not even consider this job when it receives `notifyCommit`. Even when it does consider jobs for triggering, I am sure it does it in a more efficient manner than just comparing each job's config to notify URL. I am saying this from my understanding and experience with Jenkins. I do not know the internal workings. To know that, you would need to look into Jenkins's source code, which is open source, or *[ask on here]*(http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com) - a place run by the creator of Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

When you trigger Jenkins via a Subversion post-commit hook, you're just sending a URL to the Jenkins job to start the build.

If you look at the Jenkins job configuration page and go down to the **Build Triggers** section, you'll see an entry for *Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)*. You give a name of your *build token* then, and then you can use that URL via a `wget` or `curl` command to trigger the build.

The *build token* is just a string that you can use to force a build. For example, if your Jenkins URL is `http://jenkins.vegicorp.com`, and your job name is `foo-trunk`, and you've set your build token to `BUILD_ME_NOW`, you could trigger the build with:

```
 wget http://jenkins.vegicorp.com/job/foo-trunk/build?token=BUILD_ME_NOW
```

What you can do is use a set way of how you name Jenkins jobs, so you can parse your Subversion URL to figure out the URL for the job.

For example, you setup your Subversion repo with the URL `/trunk/project` or `/branches/branch_name/project`, and you setup your Jenkins jobs to be `project-trunk` or `project-branch_name`.

You can look at the output of the `svnlook changed` command in your pre-commit hook. You'd chop off the file and directory names, so you just have the project name, and whether the project is on the trunk or a branch.

Then, you'd use that information to munge a build trigger URL. For example, I find that all of the files are under:

```
 /trunk/foo
```

I know this is my `foo` project under trunk, and the Jenkins job should be called `foo-trunk`. From there, I can figure out that the URL should be `$JENKINS_URL/job/foo-trunk?token=BUILD_ME_NOW`

With luck, there is a `foo-trunk` project (Be prepared to handle errors from `wget` in your post-commit trigger) and running:

```
 wget $JENKINS_URL/job/foo-trunk?token-BUILD_ME_NOW
```

will trigger the build.

People like this because they can trigger the build immediately after a commit instead of waiting for the next minute. With CVS, you cannot use polling because polling CVS builds takes so much time and resources.

However, I don't find this an issue with Subversion. Subversion polling is fast and takes few resources. And, I don't mind the fact that I don't build immediately after a commit and an occasional double commit where two people commit changes within the same build isn't a big issue with me. Plus, if Jenkins happened to be down, the build won't be triggered if I depend upon a post-commit hook. If I use the standard *Poll SCM* trigger, Jenkins will trigger the build once it does come back up.

One place where triggering via post-commit trigger can be helpful is where you use build parameters. For example, instead of a separate `foo` build for each branch, I define on `foo` Jenkins project, and one of my parameters is the *branch* I want to build (or trunk). Now, my post-commit trigger can trigger the build for the correct branch.

I thought the [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) had an example of a post-commit Subversion trigger. There is one for [CVS](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-UsingapostcommittriggerinCVS) would should give you an idea how it works.

---

Found this [post-commit hook](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-Postcommithook) on the Subversion plugin page for Jenkins.

Comment: You don't have to code the job name for each post-commit. You notify Jenkins that there is a change to certain repo, and Jenkins figures out which jobs use that repo and will trigger them (if SCM polling is setup, else they are ignored). `http://<jenkinsurl>/subversion/<repo_UUID>/notifyCommit`

Comment: Yes. I see that in the post-commit hook for the Subversion plugin. I wish I had read the documentation on the Subversion plugin before I wrote my post. The SVN plugin comes with Jenkins and is pretty simple to figure out, so I never looked at the doc until I looked for the hook. Still: The reason I would do this is to trigger parameter builds (have one Jenkins project which handles all builds for the project no matter what branch). In that case, you need to write a post-commit trigger to trigger the build itself.